# vue: save value of selected button

Tags: api, vue.js, radio-button

In my webapplication the user can rate a booking. He can select the like or dislike button.
[image]

My code looks like this:

```
 <div class="col-4 col-form-label">
                    <div
                      class="btn-group"
                      role="group"
                      aria-label="Basic example"
                    >
                      <Field
                        type="radio"
                        class="btn-check"
                        name="options-outlined"
                        id="success-outlined"
                        autocomplete="off"
                        checked
                        :value="true"
                      />
                      <label
                        class="btn btn-outline-success"
                        for="success-outlined"
                      >
                        <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i> Super!</label
                      >

                      <Field
                        type="radio"
                        class="btn-check"
                        name="options-outlined"
                        id="danger-outlined"
                        :value="false"
                        autocomplete="off"
                      />
                      <label
                        class="btn btn-outline-danger"
                        for="danger-outlined"
                        ><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i> Nicht so</label
                      >
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

I try now to save the value of the selected button. When the user selects the "like" I need so send this value to my api.

But I don't know how to read the value of the selected button. Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differenct options to work with that problem.

I would prefer to add `click-events` in your `<Field>` and work with them in the `methods` - like this:

```
<Field @click="Super()"/>
<Field @click="NichtSo()"/>
```

and than go to your methods and do it like following:

```
methods: {
  Super() {
    //send data to API when it's good
  },

  NichtSo() {
    //do something else
  }
}
```

Think this is the easiest way to do something like that.

**Additional Info: You can also use `v-model` to solve this problem.**

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly with click-events. I just set my boolean true or false in my methods :)